# Socket.io Task threw exception IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, json, kotlin, socket.io, engine.io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/875T9.png)

When I try to connect to the server in Socket.io, I get this error: I just tried to connect and the application crashed.

```
Task threw exception
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                                                                                        at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:290)
                                                                                                        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(ByteBuffer.java:820)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.decodePayload(Parser.java:280)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling._onData(Polling.java:137)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.onData(Polling.java:107)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(PollingXHR.java:127)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: EventThread
                                                                                                    Process: com.package.name, PID: 24625
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                                                                                        at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:290)
                                                                                                        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(ByteBuffer.java:820)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.decodePayload(Parser.java:280)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling._onData(Polling.java:137)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.onData(Polling.java:107)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(PollingXHR.java:127)
                                                                                                        at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

I just wanted to connect to the server

Comment: It seems like the payload is quite large. Could you check inside your dev tools in the browser what data you sent to the server during the connecting?

Comment: I don't know how to do this

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I would suggest you include some sample source code within the question.  Also, it is generally recommended that you not reference external images or shares in a question since those links may break in the future and others would not benefit from your question or the answers.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this error occurred to me was due to the Windows firewall. When I tested it on a physical device, not the emulator, the problem was resolved.